# get Mysql Event status

Tags: mysql, sql, scheduler, mysql-event, mysql-routines

I can get event in mysql by

```
SHOW EVENTS LIKE 'e29'
```

but it is giving all information. it is like

```
select * from ....
```

My need is that i want to get the **`STATUS` of a particular event**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Show events` is not a regular statement that returns a `cursor` to read on.

You have to query `information_schema.events` to know `status` of an `event`.

```
mysql> select event_name, status -- from events where event_name =
    -> from information_schema.events where event_name = 'event_scheduling_sample';
+-------------------------+---------+
| event_name              | status  |
+-------------------------+---------+
| event_scheduling_sample | ENABLED |
+-------------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: thanks, i even don't know about the `information_schema`, after this i will surely read about it.

Comment: Documentaion on [*`Information_Schema`*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-schema.html#idm47566336848448)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
select @@event_scheduler;
```

to show the status.